# How to set a field received from a SQL query as a parameter of another stored procedure in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have this problem: I'm using Crystal Reports as reporting tool, and in one of my reports I have two stored procedures.

The first one retrieves 3 columns (let's call them A, B and C). And the second one retrieves two columns (D and E) but the problem is that this second stored procedure uses A (from the first stored procedure) as a parameter.

So, the data from the second stored procedure depends on the "N" entries retrieved by the first stored procedure in the column A.

Is it possible to attach the field "A" as a parameter of the second stored procedure from Crystal Reports? Or should I do this from SQL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your report is going to view each stored procedure as a database, and you typically only want one database for a report.  Trying to use more than one database will usually result in a warning message from crystal reports alerting you to multiple starting points in your database.

To get around this, I would recommend using a subreport.  Your main report will use the first stored procedure to get columns A, B, and C.  Then you create a subreport that is linked on column A, and use the second stored procedure as its database to get the remaining columns on your report.

You will need to format the subreport to remove the borders that are always on subreports by default, then you will need to carefully size and align the subreport so that the values in the columns it adds to the report are in-line with the data rows of the main report.  And I will warn you, this can be quite frustrating if you are a perfectionist like me and want everything to line up perfectly.

Alternatively, you could do some database programming and create a new stored procedure that does the work of both of the other stored procedures and returns all of the columns you need in a single dataset.  If this can be done with a query using an appropriate type of "JOIN", then this option may be more efficient than the subreport option.  However, if it ends up requiring a cursor, then I would go with the subreport option.